# Remove Bounces from SQL query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have an SQL query in order to retrieve users who have not opened a specific email (with jobid), but i can not exclude Bounces. Do you have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please post the query as text, not as a screenshot and include information about exact errors/problems you have with the existing query

Answer (score 1):

The following query retrieves information about subscribers who have opened a specific email, as identified by the JobID, and who have not bounced:

```
SELECT
    SubscriberKey,
    EmailAddress
FROM
    _Subscribers
WHERE
    SubscriberKey NOT IN (
        SELECT
            SubscriberKey
        FROM
            _Open
        WHERE
            JobID = 'specific_email_job_id'
    )
    AND SubscriberKey NOT IN (
        SELECT
            SubscriberKey
        FROM
            _Bounce
        WHERE
            JobID = 'specific_email_job_id'
    )
```

Comment: Thnank you! However, i want subscribers who have NOT opened a specific email and who have not bounced

Comment: Woops, I missed that part. I've updated my answer to only include subscribers that did not open a specific email and did not bounce.